# SurfaceHolder.Callback как добавить на activity?

Tags: java, android, callback

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Помогите пожалуйста. При реализации SurfaceHolder.Callback у меня возникли проблемы с добавлением на мое activity.

activity_coordinate_plane.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CoordinatePlane">

    <view
        class="com.example.kriss.moving.MySurfView"
        id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

CoordinatePlane.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CoordinatePlane extends AppCompatActivity {
    public MySurfView SurfV;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_coordinate_plane);
    }
}
```

MySurfView.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MySurfView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private Draw drawThread;
    int n = 3;
    public MySurfView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        drawThread = new Draw(getHolder());
        drawThread.setRunning(true);
        drawThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        drawThread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                drawThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (n) {

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Draw.java (на всякий случай):

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class Draw extends Thread {
    private Paint p,p1,p2,p3;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Canvas c;
    public int n = 0, r = 50;
    public int X0,Y0,X1,Y1;

    Draw(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder){
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        p1 = new Paint();
        p1.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        p2 = new Paint();
        p2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        p2.setStrokeWidth(12);
        p3 = new Paint();
        p3.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    }

    boolean running, painting = false;
    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }
    public void setPainting(boolean painting) {
        this.painting = painting;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running){
            synchronized (surfaceHolder){
                if(painting) {
                    c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    c.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                    for(int i = 0; i < c.getHeight()/50+1; i++){
                        c.drawLine(X1-X0,i*50+Y1-Y0, c.getWidth()+X1-X0,i*50+Y1-Y0, p3);
                    }
                    for(int i = 0; i < c.getWidth()/50+1; i++){
                        c.drawLine(i*50+X1-X0,0+Y1-Y0, i*50+X1-X0,c.getHeight()+Y1-Y0, p3);
                    }
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Canvas c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    c.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                    for(int i = 0; i < c.getHeight()/50+1; i++){
                        c.drawLine(0,i*50, c.getWidth(),i*50, p3);
                    }
                    for(int i = 0; i < c.getWidth()/50+1; i++){
                        c.drawLine(i*50,0, i*50,c.getHeight(), p3);
                    }
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы написали что возникли проблемы, а какие именно? Добавьте в вопрос, так будет понятно  на что обращать внимание при просмотре кода.

Comment: добавил фото вылетающей ошибки

Comment: Ошибки выкладывайте текстом!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вью, размещённых в макете обязан быть объявлен конструктор с двумя параметрами `(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` - именно он будет вызван при создании вью инфлейтером.
Добавьте его, либо измените существующий:

```
     public MySurfView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);
         getHolder().addCallback(this);
     }
```